# Spark Print the Shape of my DataFrame in Scala

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark

There is a function in Pandas that calculates the shape of my DataFrame which eventually is the result like

```
[total number of rows, total number of columns]
```

I have the following function that I can use in PySpark to get the shape of my DataFrame:

```
print((df.count(), len(df.columns)))
```

How do I do the same in Scala? Is this also an efficient way to do it like this for larger datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is almost the same as in python. Looking at the [documentation of DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html), you can see that there are two interesting methods; [`count()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#count()) and [`columns()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#columns()), which exactly do what you want.

`count()` returns the number of rows in the `DataFrame`, and `columns()` returns an array of all column names. To get the amount of columns, you'll just have to get the length of it.

TL;DR `df.count()` for the row amount and `df.columns.length` for the column amount.